# How to use switch statement that involves instantiation in cases?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have an instance variable `piece` that is of type `Object`. It is instantiated as one of several classes in my program as a part of a `switch` statement as follows:

```
public Object getRandomPiece() {
        int random = (int)(Math.random()*8);
        switch(random) {
        case 0: case 1:
            _piece = new Piece1();
        }
        return _piece;
    }
```

Note that there are multiple cases, I have just summarized it in this snippet. My problem is that after giving `_piece` its value from the `switch` statement and returning it, I cannot access any of its new class's methods (example, methods from class `Piece1`). How should I approach this?

Comment: Program to a common `Piece` interface. Also, you could just `return new Piece1();`

Answer (score 1):

Program to a *common* `Piece` interface. If you don't use object state, prefer to make your method `static`. I would prefer a [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) over `Math.random()`, and I would prefer to avoid unnecessary local temporary variables. Putting that together, it might look something like

```
public static Piece getRandomPiece() {
    switch (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(8)) {
    case 0: case 1:
        return new Piece1();
    }
    return null;
}
```